# Can m be an arbitrary positive integer for the given expression?

Tags: calculus, number-theory

I am an electrical engineer and I am having a math-related problem hope somebody could help me out.

Assuming that:

$$a=\sum_{i=1}^{N} c_{i}b_{i}$$  where $a, b_{i}, N$ are positive number and $0<c_{i}<1$,  $\sum_{i=1}^{N} c_{i} =1$.
Also assume that there are `m` elements of $b_{i}<a$.

Question:

Can `m` be an arbitrary positive integer (of course, smaller than `N` ) or is there some restriction for `m`?

(English is not my native language so please ask me for anything that is not clear.)

Answer (score 1):

$m$ can be $N-1$ since, for some small quantity $d$, define $$b_N=a+\frac{d}{c_N}(1-c_N)$$ and define the other $N-1$ of the $b_i$ to be $a-d$.

Comment: So m can be any positive number from 1 to N-1?

Comment: Yes, that's right.